# cv2 cameraCalibrate, reverse imgSize or not?

Tags: opencv

In [this opencv article](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html), the image size is reversed when calibrateCamera() is called (note the **gray.shape[::-1]**)

`ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1],None,None)`

The [Function Documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#calibratecamera) simply says this parameter is the "Size of the image used only to initialize the intrinsic camera matrix".  I am confused by why the image size needs to be reversed here (assuming the article is correct).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image size is an OpenCV Size type, which is (width, height), whereas the shape of the image is (rows, cols).

The code reverses the (rows, cols) shape to (cols, rows) to get something equivalent to a (width, height) size type.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure how people are supposed to know this from the documentation though :(